# $V1,V2,V3$ Orthonormal.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $v_1,v_2,v_3$ vectors in $R^3$. Assume that ${v_1,v_2,v_1+v_3}$ is an orthonormal base.

Compute $||v_3||$.

Well, I started by saying that $(v_1+v_3) \bullet (v_1+v_3) = 1$.

And, $v_1 \bullet (v_1+v_3) = 0$

From here, I need your help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** From this relation
$$
\begin{align}
0
&=v_1\cdot(v_1+v_3)\\
&=\|v_1\|^2+v_1\cdot v_3\\
&=1+v_1\cdot v_3
\end{align}
$$
we can compute $v_1\cdot v_3$. Then from
$$
\begin{align}
1
&=(v_1+v_3)\cdot(v_1+v_3)\\
&=\|v_1\|^2+2v_1\cdot v_3+\|v_3\|^2\\
&=1+2v_1\cdot v_3+\|v_3\|^2
\end{align}
$$
we can compute $\|v_3\|$.

Comment: Got it now. I just didn't know that $||v_1||^2$ = 1

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track:
$$\|v_3\|^2 = \|(v_1 + v_3) - v_1\|^2 = (v_1 + v_3, v_1 + v_3) - 2(v_1 + v_3, v_1) + (v_1, v_1) = 1 - 0 + 1 = 2,$$
since $v_1 + v_3$ and $v_3$ are orthonormal.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
$$\begin{eqnarray}v_1 \bullet v_3 &=& v_1 \bullet (v_1 + v_3 - v_1) \\
&=& v_1 \bullet (v_1+v_3) - ||v_1||^2 \\
&=& -1
\end{eqnarray}$$
and
$$\begin{eqnarray}(v_1+v_3) \bullet (v_1+v_3) &=& v_1 \bullet (v_1+v_3) + v_3 \bullet (v_1 + v_3) \\
&=& v_1 \bullet v_1 + v_1 \bullet v_3 + v_3 \bullet v_1 + v_3 \bullet v_3 \\
&=& ||v_1||^2 + 2 (v_1 \bullet v_3) + ||v_3||^2 \\
\end{eqnarray}$$
which yields that
$$\begin{eqnarray}||v_3||^2 &=& ||(v_1+v_3)||^2 - ||v_1||^2 - 2(v_1 \bullet v_3) \\
&=&  2\end{eqnarray}$$
Thus $||v_3|| = \sqrt 2$.

Comment: Everything up to "which yields..." is correct. The value given for $\|v_3\|$, however, is not.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I will correct it.

Comment: Why $||v_1||^2 = 1$?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: since $v_1$ is a member of an orthonormal basis, $\|v_1\|=1$.

Comment: I'm going back to read some more on orthonormals.

Comment: I even wrote that the $(v_1+v_3) \bullet (v_1+v_3) = 1$.. Gawd :(